# Using guard-minitest on a single Ruby file

Tags: ruby, testing, guard, minitest

I'm clearly doing something wrong. I'm trying to write and test plain ruby in a single file. I want guard to watch the file and the test file and run minitest any time either file changes.

So, two files: game.rb and game_test.rb

game.rb

```
class Game
end
```

game_test.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './game'

class GameTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_truth
    assert true
  end
end
```

I also have a Guardfile that looks like this:

```
notification :terminal_notifier

guard 'minitest', test_folders: '.' do
  watch('game.rb')
  watch('game_test.rb')
end
```

Now, I'm probably forgetting something, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

If I start guard and press Enter, "Run All" happens and the tests run.. at least most of the time. However, I have to press Enter for it to happen.

Also, if I make a change to the files nothing happens. I've tried putting gem 'rb-fsevent' in a Gemfile and running with "bundle exec guard" but that doesn't seem to help either.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm going nuts.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first "watch" definition will simply pass "game.rb", which is not a test file so it won't be run.
The second "watch" is correct so when you save "game_test.rb", the tests should run.

This should be a more correct Guardfile:

```
notification :terminal_notifier

guard 'minitest', test_folders: '.' do
  watch('game.rb') { 'game_test.rb' }
  watch('game_test.rb')
end
```

Comment: So, I tried that and had no luck. The only thing I could get working was   watch('game.rb') { './game_test.rb' } with the relative directory in there. I really don't understand why. Any thoughts?

Comment: If it's any consolation, I have the same problem. I had to do same thing for both files (the equivalent of `watch('game.rb') { './game_test.rb' }; watch('game_test.rb') { './game_test.rb') }`.

Comment: That's weird, don't hesitate to [report any issue to guard-minitest](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues/new) (also be sure to run Guard in debug mode, just start it with the `--debug` flag). Also, I advise you to take inspiration from the [guard-minitest's Guardfile template](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/blob/master/lib/guard/minitest/templates/Guardfile#L3-L5).